# Should I use ThreadPool or IntentService for my application?

Tags: android, multithreading, intentservice

Hi i am implementing Sticker Feature in my app. Here user can download multiple sticker pack in background like Viber and Line.

I m a little bit confused of the what i use :  Thread or IntentService.

also if user go to Sticker pack which is downloading or in queue then i need to show there.

After download i need to store it in database.

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IntentService has the advantage that the Service will be correctly started and stopped, when  its daemon thread is busy.  Communicating with an IntentService (using intents) is also simple and provides excellent isolation and thread safety.

If the IntentService is too restrictive (single threaded; one way, Parcelable communications), then you might want to roll your own bound ExecutorService.  This is a fair amount of work: you need to manage starting and stopping the Service, handle binding and unbinding the service from client Activities, all the time being careful of thread safety.

... actually, I'm surprised there isn't a library, out there, to do this.  It is such a common need.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Service` with `ThreadPoolExecuter` instead of `IntentService`.

Comment: means for every request i need to start a service??

Comment: Yes for every Sticker bundle.. And when you do this you'll get the instance of already running instance of your service since Services are  single-instance. .And in your service you'll have a TPE that will add the tasks in the Task Queue